# How to pass a value to a NSView SubClass

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, clock

i created a clock by SubClassing the NSView. now i want create many clocks programatically and  pass the time zone value to each and every clock. how can i pass the desired timeZone value to the subClassed NSview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a variable in the .h of the class:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *timeZone
```

And reference it where you create the clock:

```
myNewClock.timezone = "GMT"
```

Comment: the property was not setting while the view was running but it accepts at the time of initiation of object

Comment: You need to set the property when you create the view

Comment: i set property as `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tZone;` in subclass header file

Comment: I dont understand your question, can you edit your main question and add the code?